# programmatically remove an item from cxradiogroup

Tags: delphi, devexpress

This code adds an item:

```
procedure TForm3.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
cxRadioGroup1.Properties.Items.Add;
cxRadioGroup1.Properties.Items[cxRadioGroup1.Properties.Items.Count -1].Caption := 'new item 1';
end;
```

But how do you remove it?

Comment: FWIW, I bet that `Add` returns the index of the new item. I would also hope that you can pass the caption as an argument to `Add`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was going to second that bet, but we would loose it. cxRadioGroup.Properties.Items.Add does not accept a string and it does return a TcxRadioGroupItem instead of an index ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do

```
cxRadioGroup1.Properties.Items.Delete(1);
```

Where 1 is the RadioButton index.